Azure DevOps Webhook Not Triggered on Work Item Removal
I'm contacting you because my Azure DevOps webhook isn't receiving notifications when Testcase work items are removed. The webhook feature works properly for updates and creations, but deletions are not triggering any responses.
Could you please investigate if there's a known issue with Azure DevOps regarding webhooks and work item removal events? I've tired this with webook settings before removing a TestCase

I've tried with a specific work item type, not working
I've tried with a [any] work item type, not working
I've tried with the TEST button to send a defaulft POST request to My webhook, it works

